# Rename surname and givenName of contact object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can someone please tell me how I can rename `sn` and `givenName` of a contact object in active directory?

This is how I query the data in my contacts OU:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {(ObjectClass -eq "contact") -and (givenName -like "*myName*") } -Properties sn, givenName -SearchBase "OU=contacts,DC=domain,DC=name"
```

From Microsoft:

> To modify the given name, surname and other name of a user, use the
>   Set-ADUser cmdlet

My goal is to modify the values of both properties because I have text that is all in lowercase and I was hoping to use something like:

```
$TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$TextInfo.ToTitleCase("one-two three")
Desired Output: One-Two Three
```

to get a capital letter for each word.

Some examples would be great.

If you know of a GUI-Tool that does what I need then please share as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the attributes on a contact AD object you will need to use the `Set-ADOject` Cmdlet, with the `-Replace` parameter. `Set-ADUser` will only set attributes of an AD object of type user.

The following code will take the `full name` of the contact object, search for it in AD and then change the `GivenName`, `SN` and `DisplayName` to title case.

I have added the `DisplayName` as this field is not automatically update when you change the first and last name, but you can delete this part if it's not needed.

```
$fullname = "My Name"
$contact = Get-ADObject -Filter {(ObjectClass -eq "contact") -and (Name -like $fullname)} -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=contacts,DC=domain,DC=name"   

$TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo

$GivenNametoTitleCase = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($contact.givenName).ToLower())
$SNtoTitleCase = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($contact.sn).ToLower())
$DisplayNametoTitleCase = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($contact.DisplayName).ToLower())

$contact | Set-ADObject -Replace @{GivenName=$GivenNametoTitleCase;`
                                   sn=$SNtoTitleCase;`
                                   DisplayName=$DisplayNametoTitleCase;}
```

Comment: I would be curious if this works in practice. As LDAP is generally case insensitive, usually changing the case only is not seen as a modify. Please let us know.

Comment: @jeemster Worked fine when I tested it in our Active Directory. I think the `-Replace` parameter might clear the attribute before replacing it.